# Difference between 'talking nonsense' and 'talking blather'?

Tags: word-choice

1. I have encountered many people like you who talk nonsense.
2. I have encountered many people like you talking blather.
3. I have encountered many people like you talking nonsense.

Is there any difference between *talking blather* and *talking nonsense*? If there is, what is this? Which one is best choice for the above case and why? And what can be the another usage of rest choice?

Another query is- *are first and third sentence same*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, "talking blather" and "talking nonsense" have the same meaning.  Subjectively, I feel that "blather" is more foolish and playful but "nonsense" is more serious.  However, it is more usual to say "blathering" rather than "talking blather", since "blather" is also a verb.  "Blather" is also more pejorative, it implies that the speaker has a negative opinion about what is being said.

The first and third sentences are different.  In the first sentence, I meet people and those people talk nonsense.  In the third sentence, the people that I meet are talking nonsense when I meet them.  The first sentence describes who they are, the third sentence describes what they are doing when I meet them.